# Is the Android SE app transmission encrypted?

Tags: discussion, android-app, ssl

I’d like to know the transmission of SE  Android app is encrypted or not with https. Please make me confirm.

Comment: If I could use wireshark I will be able to capture the packet whether it's encrypted or not. So, I used Android DDMS instead. It seems be all packets is HTTP1.1 except for the authentication which is handled by Google accounts.

Comment: Yeah, I really doubted that the Android app was encrypted, especially since it is still in Alpha.  Better to get the app working properly first, before putting in the fancy goodies.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The Android app actually was released already; it's the iOS app that's in alpha right now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The app [is using the Stack Exchange API](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-for-android-is-here/#comment-86353), which requires HTTPS to be used whenever a user access token is transmitted.

I did an inspection of traffic to/from my phone, and confirmed the app does connect to a Stack Exchange IP address (198.252.206.140) over HTTPS whenever a network based action is taken.

But, I don't have access to the app source code so I can't be 100% sure. As far as I can tell, all network traffic related to the app is handled via secure tunnels. Including the push notifications which go through Google's servers.

Comment: Yep, the app only uses https://, since, well, it *has* to.